# Docker - MySQL containers on using the same volume of a data-only container

Tags: mysql, docker, volumes, data-containers

Currently, I'm trying to figure out on how to run multiple MySQL containers that uses the same volume from a data-only container. After running the first one and successfully created my database and records in there, I tried to run another new MySQL container and faced this error:

```
Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet', system error: 0
```

I have mapped different ports to host 3306 using the containers. What's the problem? o.O

Comment: This sounds like a horrible idea.   Why would you want two competing mysql instances pointed at the same data?

Comment: It is impossible to get several mysql instances to share the same data files. What is it you want the system to do? Is it because you want to share the load across several instances or something else?

Comment: sounds like what you're trying to do is called Replication.